# C# - constant property is equivalent to lambda expression?

Tags: c#, properties, lambda

I picked up C# again, came back after a long work in Java, and as you may expect, I got very interested in properties(oh the Java burden), therefore I started to explore them a bit and came up with this.

```
private static float Width {
    get { return 0.012f; }
}
```

After a bit of tinkering, I realized this works too(lambda expression?).

```
private static float Width => 0.012f;
```

Now please help a fellow Java developer here to understand what is exactly the difference? What the former can do that the latter cannot and vice versa.

Comment: Which version of C# are you using. C# 6.0 has some new features around initializing properties.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Newest one available

Comment: You have the new features then! ;-) I added an answer below with a full explanation.

Comment: And welcome back to .NET! :-)

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Thank you! Working with Java was mostly... a disaster.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> what is exactly the difference?

Both ways define a getter only property. The latter simply uses C# 6's new feature called ["Expression Bodied Members"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), specifically these are "Expression Bodied Properties", which allow you to use the fat arrow syntax and are merely syntax sugar.

If you look at what the [compiler generates](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfGW1wAnMDypoYKddwBmRPupgB1IcgAWMALwA+GAAYAdHYCMAJh05ZQAAA=), you'll see:

```
private static float Width
{
    get
    {
        return 0.012f;
    }
}
```

Which is identical to your getter only declaration.

These can also be applied to one-liner methods as well:

```
public int Multiply(int x) => x * x;
```

Comment: for more information about C# 6.0 look at: [C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: Do I have any disadvantages in using just the "Expression Bodied Properties" rather than writing a getter only property manually? As the former is much more readable than the latter.

Comment: @Israelg99 It is only syntactical sugar, nothing more. The compiler will still generate the same code under the covers. Use whichever you and your teammates find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

There are equal.

```
private static float Width => 0.012f;
```

The `Width` is a getter only property just like your first example; 
The difference is merely only syntactic sugar.

ref:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplification of the language under C# 6.0 and are called 'Expression Bodied Functions / Properties'.

The idea is to simplify the syntax and allow you to set values for functions and properties in a shorter format.

Visual Studio magazine has an article on it here:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/03/c-sharp-6-expression-bodied-properties-dictionary-initializer.aspx

Comment: I will be using this new 'Expression Bodied Functions / Properties' rather than my former example. when I researched about this on StackOverflow I saw many users define the getter only property manually, which as I see now, it's an outdated information.